# ContentNote Insertion through DataLoader

Tags: data-loader, import, data-import

I see ContentNote has been introduced as enhanced note feature, Can anyone let me know in what format I need to insert the contentnote in a particular object via dataloader.io

I am getting the error

> :Error converting value to correct data type: Path

Answer (score 2):

I was able to insert the Content Note through Workbench and when I queried it shows all the fields but not the Parent ID Field which means that we can't associate it with any Record via API or Dataloader.

Here is the screenshot of the workbench: [image: worbench Image]

But this is having the Properties to share with People, Group when you open the record of Content Note. [image: Note Properties]

But when I created a new Note from the Related List of Contact object through UI and queried from workbench still it doesn't show any ParentID field.
But when I opened the record from the Contact Object related List It is showing the ParentID in the URL. PFA [image: ParentID field in the URL]

I don't think so that there is way to associate the Content Note with the any Object through DataLoader or API.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 steps to load Notes into enhanced Notes using Salesforce dataloader (check version for newer objects availability).

> Step-1 "Uploading ContentNote"

1. Export Notes using data loader or dataloder.io
2. Convert note body into individual text files to upload to ContentNote.
3. You only need two columns, Title and Content (which is referred to physical file path).
4. INSERT using SF dataloader or dataloader.io.

> Step-2 "Upload ContentDocumentLink"

1. Export ContentNote into a CSV
2. Create another CSV (CDL_upload.csv) with ContentDocumentId, LinkEntityId, ShareType and Visibility.
3. Replace the Id column title with ContentDocumentId
4. Paste the Ids from the ContentNote export.
5. Put the Id of the Entity each note is linked to (for this, "1" of Step-1 has parent ID. Use Vlookup of Index/Match to get the parentId and put it in LinkedEntityId column here).
6. Enter the desired values in ShareType and Visibility.
7. Insert ContentDocumentLink object and Viola!

You are done. Check out [this](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Importing-Notes-to-the-ContentNote-object-using-the-Apex-Data-Loader&language=en_US) salesforce link for complete reference before migrating data into enhanced notes.

Answer (score -1):

The insertion of data into the ContentNote is a two step process. Look at the link below

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000230867&language=en_US